# Relentless Medal and Killstreak Rewards in Black Ops 2

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

Is it a bug or am I allowed to use killstreak rewards to get this medal in a match? I'm having such a difficult time getting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug.  Scorestreak rewards are not counted towards the medal.  The only kills that count toward the medal kill count are those obtained by kills with guns, explosives, or other equipment (such as the tomahawk).

Answer (score 0):

The medals relating towards kills (ie. bloodthirsty, relentless, unstoppable etc..) have to be earned by weapons/equipment that would be on your character from the 'create a class' menu.  Picking up other players weapon will also count towards your consecutive kill medals.

Examples:

**Primary Weapon** (Assault Rifles, LMGs, Shotguns, Sub-machine guns, sniper rifles)
**Secondary Weapon** (includes pistols/2nd Primary/Rocket Launchers)
**Weapons Picked Up** from fallen enemies/foes.
**Knife**(R3 default) or Combat Knife (knife that is carried when no secondary weapon is selected)
**Lethal Equipment** (frag grenade, sticky grenade, c4, clay-more, bouncing betty etc..)
**Specialty Equipment** (crossbow/tomahawk/ballistic knife)
**Direct Impact** (hitting an enemies with a non-lethal grenade but causes them to die)

---

Killstreaks are no longer based on kills, hence the new name of Scorestreaks.  They will help you to earn other Scorestreaks based on the points received not the amount of kills you have gotten. (knda cool..but at the time this kinda punishes players who were good at getting kills without dying; since capturing a flag in domination is worth 200points which is a significantly higher then the points received from kills.)  But this helps the players who constantly go after the objectives, and helps to encourage people to put away the tent, put out the fire and join the rest of the players in their attempt to conquer the objective.

Scorestreaks earn less points then a kill from an item listed under the 'Kill Medals'.